# How to center horizontally tikzpicture in beamer frame using a specific node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment

The following MWE centers my `tikzpicture` into the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \item 5  This  is very  very  very  very  very  long  to illustrate the question
  \item 6
  \end{itemize}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, below=of a] (b) {B};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, below=of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[-latex] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[-latex] (b) -- (c);
    \draw[-latex] (c) -- +(25mm, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How could I center this figure such as that the node `B` is at the center of the frame and not the center of the whole `tikzpicture` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key `center coordinate` defined as

```
\tikzset{
  center coordinate/.style={
    execute at end picture={
      \path ([rotate around={180:#1}]perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={#1},
                                  vertical line through={(current bounding box.east)})
            ([rotate around={180:#1}]perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={#1},
                                  vertical line through={(current bounding box.west)});}}}
```

and used at the beginning of the TikZ picture (works similar to `baseline` or `trim left` and `trim right`) like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[center coordinate=(b)]
```

will create a TikZ picture where—in this case—`(b)` (or to me more precise `(b.center)`) will be in the horizontal center of the TikZ picture’s bounding box.

Used with `\centering` or the `center` environment, this will mean, that the TikZ picture will be centered inside the current paragraph width (`\linewidth`). However, this will *not* automatically *center* a TikZ picture (or a coordinate inside it) at the current page.

This will fail when the current `\linewidth` is located asymmetrical in the horizontal direction, for example with two-sided documents or in a column in a two-column document.

In the example below, I use the `backgrounds` library and its `framed` key to show the extended bounding box.

I also put the TikZ picture and the `\centering` macro along with a `\par` inside a group so that text after the picture will not be centered also. You can also use the `center` environment with only the TikZ picture but this will introduce additional vertical space.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\tikzset{
  center coordinate/.style={
    execute at end picture={
      \path ([rotate around={180:#1}]perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={#1},
                                  vertical line through={(current bounding box.east)})
            ([rotate around={180:#1}]perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={#1},
                                  vertical line through={(current bounding box.west)});}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 1 \item 2 \item 3 \item 4
  \item 5  This  is very  very  very  very  very  long  to illustrate the question
  \item 6
  \end{itemize}
  {\centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[center coordinate=(b), framed]
     \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
     \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of a] (b) {B};
     \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of b] (c) {C};
     \draw[-latex] (a) -- (b);
     \draw[-latex] (b) -- (c);
     \draw[-latex] (c) -- +(25mm, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I think the `trim left` and `trim right` keys enable you get mostly what you want. They can take a coordinate as their values:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{itemize}
  \item 1
  \item 2  This  is very  very  very  very  very  long  to illustrate the question
  \item 3
  \end{itemize}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(b), trim right=(b)]
    \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, below=of a] (b) {B};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, below=of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[-latex] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[-latex] (b) -- (c);
    \draw[-latex] (c) -- +(2, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can set the coordinate of a node to the center of the page. I hope, this is what you wanted.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{TEST}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
        \node[draw=black, rectangle] (b) at (current page.center) {B};
        \node[draw=black, rectangle, left=of b] (a) {A};
        \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of b] (c) {C};
        \draw[-latex] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[-latex] (b) -- (c);
        \draw[-latex] (c) -- +(25mm, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is almost what I want: I want to center my tikzpicture horizontaly only because I may have text above and below the picture. I modified my MWE to illustrate that point, thank you.

Comment: @ManuelSelva Was about to suggest this. So you don't want it at the centre *of the frame* but only horizontally?

Comment: @cfr Yes ! I updated the question to reflect the fact that I want only horizontal centering. May be I can grab the X coordinate of current page.center ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \item 5  This  is very  very  very  very  very  long  to illustrate the question
  \item 6
  \end{itemize}
  \mbox{\tikzmark{b}}\par
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw=black, rectangle] (b) at ({pic cs:b} -| current page.center) {B};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, left=of b] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[-latex] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[-latex] (b) -- (c);
    \draw[-latex] (c) -- +(25mm, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: centred at b?]

Or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 1
  \item 2
  \item 3
  \item 4
  \item 5  This  is very  very  very  very  very  long  to illustrate the question
  \item 6
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, baseline=(x)]
    \coordinate (x);
    \node[draw=black, rectangle] (b) at (x -| current page.center) {B};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, left=of b] (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[-latex] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[-latex] (b) -- (c);
    \draw[-latex] (c) -- +(25mm, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: centred on b without a tikzmark?]

Comment: Thank you, it's almost what I want. I still have an issue in my real example where the graph is not so simple and as several lines of nodes below A,B,C resulting in a graph with a subsequent height. I edited the question to reflect the problem: the itemize following the tikzpicture overlap vertically with the tikzpicture.

Comment: @ManuelSelva You can use a different coordinate to specify `baseline` e.g. `(a)` or `(c)` or whatever. Since the picture is an `overlay`, you do have to take care of the spacing manually. But I am not sure how you can easily get horizontal centring relative to an off-centre point within the picture without relying on the `current page` nodes. So this is the best I can do right now, at least. (I created a different picture with `a` above left and `c` below right, and confirmed that e.g. `baseline=(a)` works. But you may need to add extra vertical spacing if your text is the width of the slide.)